# Redirect to page with Autorization header

Tags: javascript, web, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I have an api web in .NET that validates a user and generates a jwt token. This works perfectly. What I need is that once the token is generated, I must add it to the Authorization header and redirect it to a page with the Authorization header included.
How could I do it through javascript or on the same web api redirect to the landing page with the header?
I appreciate your help.

Comment: what do you use in the client side ?

Comment: I'm using javascript with jquery. here my code.
 `var ajaxResult = MyJs.ValidateUser(urlLogin,user,password)

        ajaxResult.success(function (result, status, xhr) {
]
            var urlToRedirect = xhr.getResponseHeader('Location');
            var ticketAuthorization = xhr.getResponseHeader('jwtToken');
            alert(ticketAuthorization);
        }); ` 

Get the token, but I don't know how to redirect with the authorization header. help me please.

Comment: what does the target of the redirect , do you control it ? is it the same domain ?

Comment: It is not the same domain, but I do control it

Comment: are you using ASP.NET Identity in the target

Comment: It is not .net, in fact it is Qlik Sense

Comment: Didn't use it, but Redirect use cockies or parameters  usaly not headers ,